# Шаблон функции для использования структуры

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, структуры

У меня есть структуры для определения точки:

```
struct point_d
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

и

```
struct point_f
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

и есть метод, который записывает в файл массив точек, этот метод статический и находится в классе export_to_file.

описание метода в h файле:

```
template<typename T>
static void save_to_bln_contour(deque<T> points, const int type_contour, const string filename);
```

метод в cpp файле:

```
template<typename T>
export_to_file::save_to_bln_contour(deque<T> points, const int type_contour, const string filename)
{
/**/
}
```

Вызываю метод так:

```
export_to_file::save_to_bln_contour<point_d>(points, 1, "test1");
```

Если этот метод включить в тот же класс, где я его вызываю, то ошибки нет. В чем дело?

Если я пишу так, как описано выше, то линковщик студии ругается с кодом ошибки LNK2019:

ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы "public: static void __cdecl export_to_file::save_to_bln_contour(class std::deque >,int,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (??$save_to_bln_contour@Upoint_d@@@export_to_file@@SAXV?$deque@Upoint_d@@V?$allocator@Upoint_d@@@std@@@std@@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z) т ЇєэъЎшш "public: void __cdecl surface_fault::get_points_intersect(class surface_res &,class fault *)" (?get_points_intersect@surface_fault@@QEAAXAEAVsurface_res@@PEAVfault@@@Z) GRD_MBA E:\Projects\GRD_MBA\GRD_MBA\surface_fault.obj   1

В студии проблемы с кодировкой.

Мне необходимо вызывать  метод **save_to_bln_contour** и для точек структуры point_d и структуры point_f.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки и код, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: @VTT, ошибка возникает при вызове метода. Код вызова  указан в вопросе. Описание ошибки добавила в вопрос.

Comment: [Материал для ознакомления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: А крякозябры с кодировкой откуда у вас вылезают?

Comment: https://ideone.com/iYxu8a все работает.

Comment: @VTT в окне ошибок отображаются.

Comment: @Naf читаемое сообщение об ошибке добавьте, а не кракозябр

Comment: и вообще, LNK2019 - это ошибка линкера. Видимо, нет определения export_to_file::save_to_bln_contour

Comment: @Croessmah где мне его нужно взять? Студия уже такой текст в окне ошибок выводит. Я не могу исправить то, что тест ошибки отображается в другой кодировке.

Comment: @Croessmah определение есть, я все уже проверила. Если закомментировать вызов функции, то ошибка при сборке проекта не возникает

Comment: @Croessmah в описании вопроса уже указано, что ошибка линкера, я это и сама понимаю.

Comment: @Naf а не смущает, что в ошибке нет ни слова о save_to_file ?

Comment: @Croessmah в вопросе указана сама суть проблемы, поэтому указала только проблемное место, разве есть какая-то разница как именован метод.

Comment: @Naf если ошибка не из-за save_to_file (а судя по ошибке не из-за него), то вся эта информация о save_to_file и о point_d/f бесполезна. Перейдите к месту ошибки, посмотрите что именно линкеру не нравится.

Comment: @Croessmah линкер не показывает конкретное место ошибки. похоже, что проблема при вызове этого метода. но что именно не так, непонятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенесите реализацию шаблона в заголовочный файл, либо инстанцируйте шаблон с заданным набором аргументов в ".cpp файле".

Объяснение ситуации ниже. Используется `gcc`, а не `cl`, но смысл один.
Суть проста - разные единицы трансляции ничего не знают друг о друге.
Компилятор генерирует код, и отдает его линковщику, а тот уже решает, какие определения и откуда брать.
Возьмём не шаблонную функцию (для простоты):

```
//func.h
#ifndef MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H
#define MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H

void foo();//Объявляем foo

#endif //MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H


//func.cpp
#include "func.h"
#include <iostream>
void foo()
{
   std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

//main.cpp
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
   foo();//используем функцию
}
```

Скомпилируем `main.cpp: g++ main.cpp -c -o main.o`

Получили файл `main.o`. Как видим, никаких ошибок нет (ключик -c как раз "сказал" компилятору, что нужно только скомпилировать в объектник и нет необходимости вызывать линковщик).
В данном случае компилятору для сборки достаточно наличия объявления.

Скомпилируем и второй файл: `g++ func.cpp -c -o func.o`

И здесь всё нормально. Теперь соберем всё это. 
Использовать также будем `g++`, он сам знает как вызвать линковщик (чтобы не морочить голову `ld`).

`g++ -o main main.o func.o`

Всё собралось. Запускаем: `./main`, всё отлично, всё работает.
Теперь поменяем `main.cpp`, например, так:

```
//main.cpp
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

Скомпилируем `main.cpp`: `g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp`

Соберем в бинарник: `g++ -o main main.o func.o`

Всё хорошо. Но ведь мы не компилировали `func.cpp` снова.
Мы лишь скомпилировали `main.cpp` и потом слинковали с уже имеющимся `func.o`.
То есть мы не тратили 100500 часов на сборку других библиотек из-за того, что поменяли `main.cpp`.
Нам достаточно было скомпилировать только измененные части.

А теперь про `undefined reference`. Возьмем эти же файлы и попробуем собрать таким образом:

`g++ -o main main.cpp`

Получили `undefined reference`. Почему?
Всё дело в том, что у компилятора при компилировании `main.cpp` есть объявление `foo`, которого ему достаточно для того, чтобы проверить правильность использования этого самого имени `foo`.
Искать где этот foo расположен будет уже линковщик. 
Но линковщик тоже не знает где эту `foo` искать, ведь мы ему не указали на `func.o`.
Поэтому он сообщает нам, что возникла такая-то вот ошибка.
Если мы ему укажем func.o, то всё будет хорошо:

`g++ -o main main.cpp func.o`

При этом заметьте, что `func.cpp` вообще уже нигде не засвечен у нас.
В `func.o` есть нужное нам определение функции `foo`, так что линковщик смог его найти.

А теперь к шаблонам.

Сначала рассмотрим случай, когда у нас нет `func.cpp`:

```
//func.h
#ifndef MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H
#define MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
}

#endif //MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H

//main.cpp
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
    foo<double>();
}
```

Соберем: `g++ -o main main.cpp`
Всё нормально.

В данном случае **foo - не функция, это шаблон функции**.
По данному шаблону компилятор может построить код.
При использовании `foo`: `foo<int>();` компилятор генерирует код функции на основании данного шаблона (*инстанцирование*), где `T` - тип `int`.
Для `foo<double>();` - аналогично, только `T` - `double`.
А теперь добавим `func.cpp` и вынесем туда реализацию `foo`:

```
//func.h
#ifndef MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H
#define MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H

template<typename T>
void foo();

#endif //MY_PROJECT_FUNC_H

//func.cpp
#include "func.h"

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
}
```

Собираем: `g++ -o main main.cpp`
и получаем `undefined reference`.

Почему? Потому что у нас есть объявление `foo`, но нет определения, поэтому компилятор не может инстанцировать функцию (сгенерировать на основании шаблона), компилятор лишь сопоставил использование - всё в порядке и отдал объектник линковщику, а линковщик не может найти реализацию, ведь он не знает где её искать.
Ну ок, соберем так:

`g++ -o main main.cpp func.cpp`
и снова `undefined reference`.

Почему, ведь мы указали где реализация?
А вот теперь здесь в игру снова вступает раздельная компиляция.
`main.cpp` скомпилирована, `func.cpp` - тоже. Друг о друге они ничего не знают.
В `main.cpp` использование `foo`, но в `func.cpp` на самом деле нет инстанцирований этого шаблона.
Почему его нет? Оно в `func.cpp` нигде не использовалось, поэтому компилятор не стал инстанцировать шаблон.
То есть, если шаблон с неким набором аргументов шаблона не используется, то компилятор не будет генерировать код для шаблона с заданным набором аргументов.
Как быть? А давайте "заставим" компилятор в `func.cpp` сгенерировать код. Как? А просто где-то используем `foo<тип>`, например:

```
//func.cpp
#include "func.h"


template<typename T>
void foo()
{
}


void bar()
{
    foo<int>();
    foo<double>();
}
```

Собираем: `g++ -o main main.cpp func.cpp`

Всё собралось и работает. Почему?
В `func.cpp` появилась функция `bar`, 
в которой используется `foo<int>` и `foo<double>`, 
и в данной единице трансляции имеется определение шаблона, 
а значит компилятор будет инстанцировать шаблон 
и теперь в `func.cpp` есть нужные определения и линкер может их найти.
Т.е. задача выполнена - мы заставили компилятор инстанцировать шаблон. 
Но для этого нам пришлось использовать другую не шаблонную функцию. 
Но есть и более адекватное решение - явное инстанцирование.
Явное инстанцирование заставляет компилятор инстанцировать шаблон с данным набором аргументов. 
Изменим `func.cpp`

```
//func.cpp
#include "func.h"


template<typename T>
void foo()
{
}


template void foo<int>();//Явное инстанцирование шаблона foo с параметром int
template void foo<double>();
```

Собираем: `g++ -o main main.cpp func.cpp`

Всё хорошо, всё собралось. 
Но, стоит добавить в main, например `foo<char>();`, 
как мы снова получим `undefined reference`, 
ведь у нас компилятор не генерировал код для данного набора аргументов (`char`).
То есть мы можем вынести реализацию шаблона в `.cpp`,
но при этом нужно будет как-то инстанцировать шаблон для нужных наборов аргументов.

Оригинал моего поста: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1798717.html#post9488987