# C++: можно ли использовать вложенный класс как возвращаемый тип метода?

Tags: c++, классы

In a nutshell, вот мой класс:

```
class List : public Collection<T> {
public:
    class Node {
    private:
        Node *_next;
        Node *_prev;

    public:
        T _data;
    };
...
}
```

Реализация какого-то метода в .cpp типа Node:

```
template <class T>
Node List<T>::*find_node(const T &data) {
    ...
}
```

Редактор пишет, что тип Node не определён. Если метод описан в .h внутри класса - всё работает. Как это поправить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655897/Вынос-методов-вложенного-класса-за-пределы-классов

Answer (score 2):

Так такого типа `Node` действительно нет. Есть `List<T>::Node`, его и указывайте.

Альтернативами для более короткого синтаксиса будут указания возвращаемого типа после списка параметров через `->` либо автоматическое определение возвращаемого типа через `auto`.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::Node find_node(const T &data) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Либо

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::Node *List<T>::find_node(const T &data) {
 ...
}
```

либо

```
template <class T>
auto List<T>::find_node(const T &data) -> Node * {
 ...
}
```

См. также
[Вынос методов вложенного класса за пределы классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655897/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)
[C++ ошибка dependent name is not a type, prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843983/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-dependent-name-is-not-a-type-prefix-with-typename-to-indicate-a-ty)

---

Однако при этом надо помнить, что реализовать методы шаблона в полноценном самостоятельном `.cpp` файле у вас все равно не получится. Определения шаблонов должны включаться везде, а не компилироваться отдельно.

См.
[Шаблоны в модуле .cpp?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164626/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-cpp)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775850/182825